# How to call a lambda expression on IQueryable object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

**Story**

I am mocking an IRepository patterned implementation. Everything is OK, but I have a problem with UpdateMany method.

**The Original Method**

The original method is using Entity Framework's query.*Update()*. Of course that expects DB contexts and some such

```
        public virtual void UpdateMany(IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, T>> entityInitializer)
    {
        query.Update(entityInitializer);
        this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

**Mocked Method**

As I don't use DB contexts, just a List of a given type, Entity's extension method for IQueryable does not work (Exception is thrown without much sensible information). My method accepts the same  arguments, but I have no idea how to parse them.

**Example expression**

```
.UpdateMany(x.IsActive, new TestStuff { IsActive = false });
```

So basically, for every active TestStuff in repository, set IsActive to false.
Of course it should not be bound to a specific object

**TL;DR**
Having a query, how to call a lambda expression on it?

Comment: So, if you can't use query lambdas, can you try doing a simple ForEach, and add an if in to control if it's active? I'm assuming you can have a list (IEnumerable) of stuff

Comment: Well that would work for this specific case, but I have to accept implemented method calls as they are provided, so I have to somehow parse both expressions - and parsing their body in text isn't really desirable

Comment: *Entity Framework's query.Update()* AFAIK there is no such standard EF method, where it comes from?

Comment: @IvanStoev Z.EntityFramework.Plus.BatchUpdate.EF6

Comment: Well, than this is quite custom method. You can't simply "call" lambda, you have to understand and reimplement the concrete method logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up reimplementing the "update" method, but it wasn't as obvious as it would seem.

BulkUpdate and Update extension classes from Z.EntityFramework.Plus.BatchUpdate.EF6.